# error TS2339: Property 'celsius' does not exist on type 'Temperature'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to make a Temperature class with typescript. The javascript version works, but typescript throws this error. Why does this example work with javascript, but fail with typescript? Here's the code to reproduce:

Temperature.js

```js
class Temperature {
    constructor(celsius) {
        this.celsius = celsius;
    }
    get fahrenheit() {
        return this.celsius * 1.8 + 32;
    }
    set fahrenheit(value) {
        this.celsius = (value - 32) / 1.8;
    }
    static fromFahrenheit(value) {
        return new Temperature((value - 32) / 1.8);
    }
}

let test = new Temperature(100);
console.log(test.celsius);
console.log(test.fahrenheit);
```

Temperature.ts

```
class Temperature {
  constructor(celsius) {
    this.celsius = celsius;
  }
  get fahrenheit() {
    return this.celsius * 1.8 + 32;
  }
  set fahrenheit(value) {
    this.celsius = (value - 32) / 1.8;
  }

  static fromFahrenheit(value) {
    return new Temperature((value - 32) / 1.8);
  }
}

let test = new Temperature(100)
console.log(test.celsius);
console.log(test.fahrenheit);
```

Successful javascript output:

```sh
➜  ch6 node Temperature.js 
100
212
➜  ch6
```

Compilation error:

```sh
➜  ch6 tsc --target es6 Temperature.ts 
Temperature.ts:3:10 - error TS2339: Property 'celsius' does not exist on type 'Temperature'.

3     this.celsius = celsius;
           ~~~~~~~

Temperature.ts:6:17 - error TS2339: Property 'celsius' does not exist on type 'Temperature'.

6     return this.celsius * 1.8 + 32;
                  ~~~~~~~

Temperature.ts:9:10 - error TS2339: Property 'celsius' does not exist on type 'Temperature'.

9     this.celsius = (value - 32) / 1.8;
           ~~~~~~~

Temperature.ts:18:18 - error TS2339: Property 'celsius' does not exist on type 'Temperature'.

18 console.log(test.celsius);
                    ~~~~~~~


Found 4 errors.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a typescript class, we need to declare properties for them to compile correctly. See [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html) for an example from the docs. When I add the property declaration, the file compiles successfully.

Temperature.ts

```js
class Temperature {
  celsius: number;
  constructor(celsius) {
    this.celsius = celsius;
  }
  get fahrenheit() {
    return this.celsius * 1.8 + 32;
  }
  set fahrenheit(value) {
    this.celsius = (value - 32) / 1.8;
  }

  static fromFahrenheit(value) {
    return new Temperature((value - 32) / 1.8);
  }
}

let test = new Temperature(100)
console.log(test.celsius);
console.log(test.fahrenheit);
```

Compilation success:

```sh
➜  ch6 tsc --target es6 Temperature.ts
➜  ch6
```